# I was planning on doing, I was going to do, I was supposed to do, Is there any difference?

Tags: sentence-meaning

You didn't do what you planned to do.  In this case, I can think of three different sentences:

> 1) I was going to do..
>   2) I was planning on doing...
>   3) I was supposed to do...

I wonder if three sentences are interchangeable.  For example:

> 1) I was going to meet with my friend yesterday.
>   2) I was planning on meeting with my friend yesterday.
>   3) I was supposed to meet with my friend yesterday.

Do they mean all the same?   If so, which is the most common? If different, could you explain it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call them all equally valid and even equally probable, more or less. I think they all pretty much mean the same thing, too.

There's even a fourth one that springs to mind:

> I was planning to meet with my friend yesterday.

(That's not any better than your three sentences, just another way to say the same thing.)

Where it gets a bit tricky, though, is if you wanted to change the *"was planning"* to *"had planned"* for some reason. This works just fine when the verb is *plan*:

> I had planned on meeting with my friend yesterday.
>   I had planned to meet with my friend yesterday.

but doesn't work when *was going to* is used:

> I <strike>had going to meet</strike> with my friend yesterday.

---

I will say this about the three sentences: they all feel like they need a little more context to sound completely natural. As written now, they feel somewhat "incomplete" (not grammatically, just informationally). This could be done by adding more information after a conjunction:

> I was going to meet with my friend yesterday, *but her car broke down*.
>   I was planning on meeting with my friend yesterday, *until my boss asked me to work late*.

Or by using the sentence to answer a question:

> *When were you going to meet with your friend?*
>   I was supposed to meet with my friend yesterday.

Comment: @J.R.Then your sentence " I was planning to ....." is much easier for me to use.  Also I didn't realize that I need to add more information to those sentences to make it clear.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

They are close, but the differences are quite subtle.

/#1 expresses a vague past intent, very casual that you might see you friend at some point.

/#2 expresses you had an expectation or desire to see your friend.

/#3 expresses you were compelled by some outside force to see your friend.  The outside force could be your friend, your boss or even a schedule you made, just not you at that moment.

Comment: I think those differences are almost imperceptible. If I have an appointment with my dentist at 1 o'clock, do I have an _intent_ to see my dentist, an _expectation_ to see my dentist, or a _commitment_ to see my dentist? I think I have all three, and it's nearly impossible to separate one from the others.

Answer (score 1):

*was going* and *was planning* in the examples roughly mean the same thing. *was planning* indicated more of a deliberate plan though.

As for [**suppose**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/suppose), this has a more indirect sense.

> *intransitive verb*
>   5) to expect or obligate (always in the passive)   ⇒ "you're supposed to telephone"

It adds an expectation of something happening. There may have been a plan but not necessarily.